# Is post to multiple friends possible for friends using same app in facebook? (after April 30th 2015)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When a user logs in to a Facebook app after April 30th 2015, the app will only be  able to list his friends who are using the app. As an App developer will I  be able to implement the usecase "logged in user should post messages to multiple friends wall" (or at least send private messages/recomendations) to multiple people in this list.

Can you please give me directions how I can do it?. 
I am looking for A server side (java api) or a client side (javascript api) solution. 
But the first question is Will it be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting to the wall of a friend is not even possible with v1.0 and it would always be spam.

For sending messages to multiple friends, you can use the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog